# I'm designing a mod-3 asynchronous counter. The circuit is expected to count from 0 to 2 and the flip flops are set as soon as q become 3

Tags: verilog

[image]

```
module mod3counter(
input clk,
output [1:0] q
);

wire rst ;
nand a1(rst,q[0],q[1]);

tff t1(clk, rst, q[0]);
tff t2(q[0],rst,q[1]);

endmodule

module tff(
input clk,rst,
output reg q
);

initial q = 0 ;

always @(negedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if(~rst) q <= 0;
    else    q <= ~q ;
end 
endmodule
```

Test bench is simply two lines of code that run the clock.

Comment: If you add four spaces at the start of each line of code, it'll be interpreted as a single block of code by the site which makes it more legible.

Comment: rst seems to be one always.

Comment: Yeah it seems working now.. Can you explain me how does race condition arise in this logic?

Answer (score 1):

Two big issues:

1. Do not have a flop asynchronously reset itself. This included indirectly through combinational logic. It might work in simulation (in your case it appears not to), but on FGPA/ASIC the pulse with has a good change of being too short and may case metastability. Adding delays to create a cleaner pulse is a band-aid; it may work on the conditions you try then unexpectedly fail with different routing, parasitic, or other deviations. It is also important to keep all asynchronous set/reset signals glitch free, else run the risk of unintended set/reset or metastability.
2. Do not use daisy-chain counters (where the q of one flop functions as the clock of another flop) are not recommended for real designs. They can have bad timing and glitchy outputs. Real flops have clock-to-q delays, you can mimic the delay in Verilog with a non-blocking delay (e.g. `q <= #1 ~q;`). String a bunch of this together and you will see the it takes longer for the value to settle.
   Daisy-chain counters are fine for learning but best if all the flops are driven by the exact same clock. Unlike point 1, a small daisy-chain counter is unlikely to cause major issues, but is a best not to get in the practice of using them.

Keep the design synchronous in one clock domain. Example:

```
always @(negedge clk or negedge rst) begin
  if (!rst) begin
    q <= 2'b00;
  end
  else if (q < 2) begin
    q <= q + 2'b01;
  end
  else begin
    q <= 2'b00;
  end
end
```

Comment: How about using an asynchronous reset?

Comment: Asynchronous are for putting the flip in a known constant state. Flops must not asynchronously reset themselves. Synchronously resetting themselves is legal.